# Print is printing entire window, not the View

Tags: cocoa

I have a simple program, for making sure the print works.

-Subclassed `NSObject` for a Controller, "`ViewController`.

-Subclassed `NSView`, `View`

Added a `custom view` to the window, set class to `View`.

Made `ViewController` delegate for `View`. 
Added Object in `IB`, set class to `ViewController`.

Added `IBOutlet` to Delegate section of `ViewController`, connected it to the the custom view on the window.

In View, have a simple `[myString drawInRect: rect]`, where `myString` is defined in the init as `@"Hi"`.

When I run, the program prints `"Hi"` in the view. When I click the "`Print`" menu item, the print preview shows the entire window.

More: I hade an earlier test program which had no print code, I ran it and the print preview showed only the view. I've got through both codes and cannot find a difference, so I am lost at why one is working and the other is not.

Do any of you know why the print preview would show the entire window instead of the view?

[EDIT]-----
I also created an extremely simple program to check and have the same issue.
Subclassed `NSView`, `MainView`
Added Custom View to Window, set class to `MainView`
Added `[str drawInRect: dirtyRect withAttributes:nil];`
(note; `NSString *str = @"Hello";`).

[More Information]-------

I added a print method as follows to the `NSView` object:

```
-(void)printPDF{
NSRect r = [self bounds];
[[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:self] runOperation];
[self dataWithPDFInsideRect:r];
}
```

Added a button to the window, linked it to an `IBAction` method in the `ViewController`:

```
-(IBAction)printToPDF:(id)sender{
  [view printPDF];
}
```

In the `ViewController` I have:

```
IBOutlet View *view;
```

This works! So, why does the default "print" menu item print the entire Window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you don't have to write any printing code and the printing just works. But, it provides default behavior (aka, print the entire window).

If you want custom printing behavior, you'd have to write your own printing method.(like you did in your extremely simple program). And you can link the default print menu item to your own printing method.

Comment: Wow, I forgot this question was still active (unanswered), I gave up on anyone responding. I appreciate your response, and my solution was exactly what you suggested - I created a custom print method and linked the print menu item to the custom method.